# Restoring inheritance to a Windows directory via Java using JNA

Tags: java, c++, windows, security, jna

I have a problem and I HOPE someone out there can give me advice!  Basically in my program I will be taking a windows folder, changing ownership, setting Access Control rules etc, for this its pretty vanilla Java using:

`Files.getFileAttributeView(target, AclFileAttributeView.class);`

The problem arises when I want to forget about a directory, and to do this I want to re-enable the inheritance to the parent directory and remove all my ACL rules.  I can remove the rules and set the owner  back again using Java however it looks like I have to go native to set the inheritance flag...

I THINK I can get a pointer to the security descriptor like this:

```
    Advapi32 advapi32 = Advapi32.INSTANCE;
    PointerByReference ppsidOwner = new PointerByReference();
    PointerByReference ppsidGroup = new PointerByReference();
    PointerByReference ppDacl = new PointerByReference();
    PointerByReference ppSacl = new PointerByReference();
    PointerByReference ppSecurityDescriptor = new PointerByReference();
    int reqSecurityInfo = Advapi32.OWNER_SECURITY_INFORMATION |
            Advapi32.DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION |
            Advapi32.SACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION |
            Advapi32.GROUP_SECURITY_INFORMATION;
    int ret = advapi32.GetNamedSecurityInfo("c:\\\\testpaths", Advapi32.SE_FILE_OBJECT, 
            reqSecurityInfo, ppsidOwner, ppsidGroup, ppDacl, ppSacl, ppSecurityDescriptor);
    if(ret != 0){
        throw new Win32Exception(ret);
    }
```

Where Advapi32.java contains:
`Advapi32 INSTANCE = (Advapi32) Native.loadLibrary("Advapi32", Advapi32.class, W32APIOptions.UNICODE_OPTIONS);`

But I really am floundering a bit here, am I on the right track or am I being an idiot? It is unfamiliar ground for me, please help!

Comment: Note: it's perfectly valid to use forward slashes as file path separators on windows, and it makes strings a bit easier to read.

Comment: Have you actually tried this?  what were the results?

Comment: Yes I have tried this, I get pointers updated in the ppsidOwner etc however I then got lost trying to convert these to the security object which belongs in WinNT.dll.  I try to instance the WinNT.dll interface and it fails because it cannot find the actual dll, however if I copy the method from the WinNT.dll I get an array not instanced exception.  Basically I think I am doing this bit wrong and was hoping someone with JNA experience could point me in the right direction?

Comment: You can generally create a new instance of any structure using an existing pointer.  You'll need to post some actual code, though, for anyone to be able to offer suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I decided the easiest way to do this was to implement the code in C# and import the simple DLL to java and call that, as an example:

```
    [RGiesecke.DllExport.DllExport]
    static void ReEnableInheretance(String dirPath)
    {
        DirectorySecurity dirSecurity = new DirectorySecurity();
        dirSecurity.SetAccessRuleProtection(false, false);
        Directory.SetAccessControl(dirPath, dirSecurity); 
    }
```

And in Java:

```
public interface MyNewLib extends Library {
    public void ReEnableInheretance(String dirPath);
}

MyNewLib myNewLib = (MyNewLib )Native.loadLibrary("MyNewLib ",MyNewLib.class);
myNewLib .ReEnableInheretance(path.toString());
```

Puts a dependency onto .net however that is not a problem for me.